# WP_User_Query does not return searches based on email

Tags: php, wordpress

Ive implemented a custom search in wordpress but the search doesnt return results when your search by user_email, only first_name & lastname work. Here is my code....

```
    $search_string = esc_attr( $search );
        $users = new WP_User_Query( array(
            'search'         => "*{$search_string}*",
            'search_columns' => array(
                'user_login',
                'user_nicename',
                'user_email',
                'user_url',
            ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'first_name',
                    'value'   => $search_string,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'last_name',
                    'value'   => $search_string,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        ) );
        $users_found = $users->get_results();
```

I cannot search by email address,... I get no results even though the code looks valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write Query for `user_email` separately also like below:-

```
$q1 = new WP_User_Query( array(
            'user_email' => "*{$search_string}*",
            'search_columns' => array(
                'user_login',
                'user_nicename',
                'user_email',
                'user_url',
            ),
       );

$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
            'search'         => "*{$search_string}*",
            'search_columns' => array(
                'user_login',
                'user_nicename',
                'user_email',
                'user_url',
            ),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'first_name',
                    'value'   => $search_string,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'last_name',
                    'value'   => $search_string,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        ) );

$unique = array_unique( array_merge( $q1->get_results(), $users->get_results() ), SORT_REGULAR  );
```

Comment: @TommyAdeniyi  glad to help you :):)